# Integral Inequality using Wirtinger's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality, harmonic-analysis

Prove that for all
$
f \in C^1[a,b]
$

$$
\forall \epsilon >0 : \ \int_{a}^{b} \lvert f^2 \lvert \,dx \ \leq (1+ \epsilon) (\frac{b-a}{\pi})^2\int_{a}^{b} \lvert f' \lvert^2 \,dx \ + (1+ \epsilon^{-1})(b-a)(\lvert f(a) \lvert ^2 +\lvert f(b) \lvert ^2)$$

You may use Wirtinger's inequality:
If
\begin{equation*}
g \in C^1[a,b] , g(a)=g(b)=0
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\ \int_{a}^{b} \lvert g^2 \lvert \,dx \ \leq (\frac{b-a}{\pi})^2\int_{a}^{b} \lvert g' \lvert^2 \,dx \ 
\end{equation*}

I'm stuck with this question and I do not even know how to start. I do not really have an idea of the  "origin" of this epsilon and how do I get this inequality.
I guess that if we want to use Wirtinger's inequality, we have to use a new function vanishing in $a,b$ but I couldn't think of one that works on it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: As you have remarked : in order to meet condition $g(a)=g(b)=0$, you can subtract to $f$ a function taking value $f(a)$ in $a$ and $f(b)$ in $b$. One is tempted to use an affine function $y=\phi(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}x + \frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{b-a}$, but the "degree of freedom" given by $\epsilon$ wouldn't be there. I would attempt to add/subtract to $\phi$ a quadratic function not very different from the linear one ; for example subtract : $\phi(x)+\epsilon(x-a)(x-b)$ to $f(x)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much for your response. I tried to use the function you suggested and there is a little problem: There is no $(1+\epsilon)$ before the integral over the derivative.